# Prove $(xa)^{2n + 2} = a^{n + 1}$ if $xax = e$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

$(xa)^{2n + 2} = (xa)^{2n}(xa)^2 = ((xa)^2)^n(xa)^2 = (xaxa)^n(xa)^2 = a^nxaxa = a^{n + 1}.$

I also have two minor problems that don't need their own separate threads.

> If $xax = b$, then $ab$ has a square root.

Let $xax = b$. Then $a(xax) = ab$.

> If $x^2ax = a^{-1}$, then $a$ has a cube root.

Let $xxax = a^{-1}$ . Then $xa(xxax)xax = xa(a^{-1} )xax = xxax = a^{-1} $. We know that if $a^{-1}$ has a cube root, so does $a$: suppose $aaa = a^{-1}.$ Then $a^{-1}(aaa)a^{-1} = a^{-1}(a^{-1})a^{-1} \to a = a^{-1}a^{-1}a^{-1}.$

Please, check my work.

Comment: You showed $xax$ is a cube root of $a^{-1}$.  Why did you suppose that $a^3 = a^{-1}$?

Comment: Would I have been able to suppose that $a^3 = a^{-1}$ if I made it a standalone problem that precedes the one where $(xax)^3 = a^{-1}?$

Comment: Supposing that $a^3 = a^{-1} \Rightarrow a^4 = e$.  You showed that $xax$ is a cube root of $a^{-1}$, so $(xax)^{-1}$ is a cube root of $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two look good. For the third one, everything is fine until you suppose $aaa=a^{1-}$. Why does this hold?

For the first problem a shortcut is to observe that $(xaxa)=a$. Then $(xa)^{2n+2}=(xaxa)^{n+1}$.

For the last problem, here is a **hint:**

$$xxax = a^{-1} \Rightarrow xxaxa=e \Rightarrow xaxa=x^{-1} \Rightarrow xaxax=e$$

One more step and you are done.

Comment: $xaxax = e \to xaxaxa = a?$